# Does this sentence follow a correct subject verb agreement rule?

Tags: verb-agreement

The increased earth temperature cause increase in the global warming.

Answer (score 1):

***The increased earth temperature*** is one singular quantity.

Therefore it must follow a singular verb as;

> The increased earth temperature ***causes*** increase in the global warming.